# Print only one page of a multiple page pdf

Tags: java, printing

I have a document which has multiple pages. I want to print first all pages and then only the first page again.

Is there a attribute which I can set (PrintRequestAttributeSet) to make sure it only prints the first page? I didn't find a list of all attributes which I can set with PrintRequestAttributeSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [PageRanges](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PageRanges.html) attribute to print only the first page of the document:

```
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attributes.add(new PageRanges(1));
printJob.print(pdfDoc, attributes);
```

Full list of supported attributes can be found at the documentation page of [PrintRequestAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttribute.html).

Comment: if i have 6 page then i need to print from 6 to 4 (print revert)
how should i do? thanks advance